# Testing controllers that only redirect in laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I don't know if people test controllers these days or if you just test the service providers and the underlying entities. How ever, I have a controller that essentially does: `if user failed to fill in form, redirect, if they did but didn't choose x redirect, if they did and chose x redirect.` Essentially its a case of "I don't care what you do we will redirect."

Now with laravel you have handy methods like visit x and see y. accept in this case My stuff  that I am testing lives under a subdomain and theres no easy way to test that. (from other questions I have asked on stack).

The main issue I run into with doing the `visit` idea is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler' not found in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php on line 76
```

I don't get this issue when trying to `visit` non subdomain routes.

So when I try and do the following:

```
    $this->action('POST', 'EveMarketSearchController@search', []);
    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('eve.search');
```

Which will redirect back to the search page because you haven't filled in the forms. I get:

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://eve-market.adambalan.local/search'
+'http://eve-market.adambalan.local'
```

So my question is:

**How do you write tests for controller actions under subdomains that regardless of inout will redirect either back, to some other page for more options to select from or to a search result page?**

Comment: Hey Kyle, when you say 'subdomain', what are you referring to?

Comment: @mike I'll let you look at the URLs above and tell me what you think a sub domain is or "what I'm referring too" ;)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing  I should have read this first! Worked it out

Comment: Wow if only I didn't have my routes set up like that ... Oh wait ... I do. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nope! None here yet. Curious about the answer though. :D

Comment: There is no answer.  Using call is the only way